# Displaying a text when looking on a GameObject in Unity VR

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to use Google VR asset for unity and it is pretty easy, I have already built the most of the things in my project.

I have just one issue, I don't find a way to display text to the player...

In my project the user walks around a model, and when he looks on a specific part of it, a window with the proper information pops up.

I have tried using OnGui function, but for no avail...

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a world-space canvas or a 3D Text. You will probably also want some billboarding (the text facing the user).

I often use this helper for this (just drag to a new gameobject):

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(TextMesh))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Billboarded3dText : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool yawOnly = false;
    public float minimalViewDistance = 0.5f;

    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    private TextMesh textMesh;


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        textMesh = GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    }


    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        var cam = Camera.main;
        if (cam == null) return;

        var lookDir = transform.position - cam.transform.position;
        if (yawOnly) lookDir.y = 0;

        if(Vector3.SqrMagnitude(lookDir) < minimalViewDistance)
        {
            meshRenderer.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            meshRenderer.enabled = true;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookDir);
        }
    }


}
```